# Android Studio integrate Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to create a sample to display Google Maps on an Android app with Android Studio. My intention is to support API level 14 and over. When I create a new project with Google Map Activity, it works correctly but uses **SupportMapFragment** and not **MapFragment** which is advised to use with with API level 12 and higher.
I have followed [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) guide on Google developers.

I am not able to see the map. The app closes when I want to show the activity which has the map.  Error is on the line which set the content view.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
```

And my activity_map.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

In buld.gradle (Module: app) i have the following line in dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.albanianwonders.googlemapapiv2" >


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
         The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <activity android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY_IS_HERE" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Error that I get is

```
28088-28088/com.albanianwonders.googlemapapiv2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.albanianwonders.googlemapapiv2/com.albanianwonders.googlemapapiv2.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:360)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1932)
        at com.albanianwonders.googlemapapiv2.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ck.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ab.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aa.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:879)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1155)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4916)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
```

Am I missing something in the configuration?
How to verify that I have imported correctly Google Play Services in Android Studio?

Comment: "Error is on the line which set the content view." -- what is the error? If you switched to `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`, did you also switch the activity to inherit from `Activity` (instead of `ActionBarActivity`) and switch `AppTheme` to not inherit from `Theme.AppCompat`?

Comment: I have created 2 separate projects. The first from template that Android Studio offers and the second without any activity. I created all the files myself.

Comment: I added the error on the question.

Comment: Plus one more problem: seems like you have not provided correct Google Maps API keys in your manifest.

Comment: I have removed when i posted the question. In my project is there, instead of **MY_API_KEY_IS_HERE**

Comment: According to that error, the version of the app project that you ran is lacking the listed permissions. They show up in the manifest in your question, so I would have to presume that the app you ran, and got the stack trace for, is using a different manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare they are not for different manifest I just checked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all that you spend your time helping me.
I found the answer myself. My mistake is that I have put `uses-permission` and `uses-features` inside the `<application> ... </application>` tags.

They **must** be placed inside the `<manifest> ... </manifest>` tags.

The correct AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.albanianwonders.googlemapapiv2" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY_IS_HERE" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have read your code ,Code is correct.you use this library

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2+'

Comment: Should I replace this with the line that currently I am using in build.gradle? I tried this and it wont work.